# Axis get reduced when using geom_sf and geom_point in R

Tags: r, maps, r-sf

The data I'm using is the following:

```
 mapa

 >Simple feature collection with 19 features and 11 fields
 >geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
 >dimension:      XY
 >bbox:           xmin: -1004502 ymin: 3132137 xmax: 1126932 ymax: 4859240
 >epsg (SRID):    25830
 >proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m 
 >+no_defs
 >First 10 features:
 >     Codigo       Texto   Texto_Alt       CCAA  Muertes  Ciudad
 >1        01   Andalucía   Andalucía  Andalucía      491  Sevilla
 >2        02      Aragón      Aragón     Aragón      284  Zaragoza
 >3        03    Asturias    Asturias   Asturias       86  Oviedo
 >...
 >      Autonomía Superficie Habitantes Latitud Longitud                       geometry
 >1     Andalucía   14035.73     703206   37.38    -6.00 MULTIPOLYGON (((280486.8 39...
 >2        Aragón   17274.89     674317   41.66    -0.88 MULTIPOLYGON (((683851.1 47...
 >3      Asturias   10602.40     224005   43.36    -5.84 MULTIPOLYGON (((271018.9 48...
 >...
```

I'm having troubles to understand why the axis in the `geom_point` gets reduced and does not plot the point on the map.

```
 mapa %>% ggplot() +
      geom_sf(aes(fill = Superficie)) +
      geom_point(aes(x = Longitud, y = Latitud ,size = Muertes), 
                 color= "red", alpha = 1/2)
```

This plots the following:

[image]

Actually the *red point* is the following:

[image]

I'm new to `sf` but I know this has something to do with the `bbox` item specified in the data code.

I have prove with `coord_sf()` to reduce the plot window but the problem persists. If I multiply by 100000 the `Latitud` and `Longitud` I can get the points closers, but the points expand.

How con it be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your map and points are not in the same projection. You can read about it [here](https://rspatial.org/raster/spatial/6-crs.html)

Comment: @IanCampbell it comes from a long sequence of joins, I can specify it if necessary but I think It would mess up the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I said in my first comment, your sf object is in the utm projection while your points are in lonlat. You can use the function `st_transform` to get the job done.

```
mapa <- st_transform(mapa, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Comment: Heck yeah. I was reading the link you gave me just when you post the answer. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Always!! do not forget to take a look on that topic.